# Given an array, find maximal sorted subset

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I want to find the maximal subset of an array which is sorted in ascending order

Say I have

```
a = [2, 1, 4, 6, 7]
a_max_subset = [1, 4, 6, 7]

b = [4, 1, 2]
b_max_subset = [1, 2] 

c = [2, 5, 13, 8, 6, 23, 33]
c_max_subset = [2, 5, 8, 23, 33]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this ?

Comment: [Largest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) perhaps?

Comment: I don't think there can be anything better than O(n) anyway, as you really have to though the array from beginning to end.

Comment: Do the elements have to appear consecutively in the original array? e.g. c = [3, 6, 4, 5, 7], is c_max_subset [3, 4, 5, 7] or [4, 5, 7]?

Comment: @samgak c_max_subset will be [3, 4, 5, 7]

Comment: Why can't b_max_subset be [4, 1]?

Comment: @Tony wanted the ascending order subset, thanks! for pointing this out. Have edited the question

Comment: Using subset is misleading. As in sets (and also in subsets) order is not important (, and there is no duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to find out is [Longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

You can find an O(N^2) implementation [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-3-longest-increasing-subsequence/). It's well explained and commented properly. Try to understand the explanation and implement it by yourself.

If you are really curious, you can check this `O(N logN)` [solution](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/) also.